# Only UPDATE rows on the same group by column value

Tags: mysql

Given a table with 3 columns and a few rows in it:

```
+--------+------------+--------+
|  name  | postalcode | toggle |
+--------+------------+--------+
| john   |      10100 |      0 |
| joe    |      10100 |      0 |
| tom    |      10100 |      0 |
| steven |      77777 |      0 |
| jerry  |      10100 |      0 |
| albert |      77777 |      0 |
| paul   |      77777 |      0 |
| mary   |      88888 |      0 |
| louis  |      10100 |      0 |
| claire |      77777 |      0 |
+--------+------------+--------+
```

I want to `UPDATE` the `toggle` value to 1 with a `LIMIT` on `N` rows, but rows with the same `postalcode` cannot have distinct values on the `toggle` column.

For example:

- If I would like to UPDATE 2 rows only `[mary]` would be updated.
- If I would like to UPDTE 4 rows, `[steven, albert, paul, claire]` would be updated.
- If I would like to UPDATE 5 rows, `[john, joe, tom, jerry, louis]` or `[steven, albert, paul, mary, claire]` would be updated.

How can I perform this operation in a convenient / performant way taking into account that I will be dealing with N rows?

Comment: Please provide expected result for clarify.

Comment: @ElChupacabra, It's already in the question, in the "For exemple" block

Comment: `Select group by Cp having count = N`

Comment: What if selected group are more than one(like in 3rd example). Which should be updated. and what what should be new toggle value if toggle value of some row(s) are different from others(in same group)

Comment: Why update 2 rows should update mary?

Comment: @ElChupacabra because 2 rows is the maximum rows I need to UPDATE but in this particular case only one can be updated.

Comment: may be 2 is max rows. so it can be anything equal or less then N

Comment: Because any other name you'd update would cause same postal codes to have different toggle values.

Comment: @PriyeshKumar this

Comment: Once you have the postal groupe by checking the count, you can update all to 0 and 1rst to 1

Comment: @PierreLebon Thank you Pierrre. Almost. It doesn't really cover the 1st example. If I do the GROUP BY postalcode HAVING count = 2, 0 rows will be returned. One possible aprox. would be count < 2, but then again, the total number of rows with count < 2 could be greater than the max N.

Comment: your issue is if count = 2 , Nothing should be update. Then if Nothing is update the rooting start again with N-1

Comment: In third case, why is should update `[steven, albert, paul, mary, claire]` when it has got perfect match of 5 rows?

Comment: try to post a solution for 1 hours pass more time editing my post and so Js to solve a "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code." M out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick version from my comment

Base Data: `select * from myTable;`

```
    +--------+------------+--------+
    |  name  | postalCode | toggle |
    +--------+------------+--------+
    | john   |      10100 |      0 |
    | joe    |      10100 |      0 |
    | tom    |      10100 |      0 |
    | steven |      77777 |      0 |
    | jerry  |      10100 |      0 |
    | albert |      77777 |      0 |
    | paul   |      77777 |      0 |
    | mary   |      88888 |      0 |
    | louis  |      10100 |      0 |
    | claire |      77777 |      0 |
    +--------+------------+--------+
```

Test Procedure take N as parameter.

If can't find postalCode with count = N, retry with N-1.
This way N=2, update Count=1.

```
    drop procedure if exists test;
    create procedure test(in tofind int)
    begin
    SET @go=1, @toFind=tofind;    
    while(@go) do
        Select  @_pc:=postalCode as pc,  @_count:=count(*) as cnt
        from myTable
        group by postalCode
        having count(*) = @toFind;

        If(@_count is null and @_count>1 ) then
            SET @toFind = @toFind-1;
        else        
            SET @go=0;    
            UPDATE myTable
            SET toggle=1 
            WHERE postalCode=@_pc;            
        end if;

    END WHILE ;
    End;
```

Call procedure wih N=3, Marry should be updated.

```
call test(3);
select * from myTable;
```

Result

```
    +--------+------------+--------+
    |  name  | postalcode | toggle |
    +--------+------------+--------+
    | john   |      10100 |      0 |
    | joe    |      10100 |      0 |
    | tom    |      10100 |      0 |
    | steven |      77777 |      0 |
    | jerry  |      10100 |      0 |
    | albert |      77777 |      0 |
    | paul   |      77777 |      0 |
    | mary   |      88888 |      1 |
    | louis  |      10100 |      0 |
    | claire |      77777 |      0 |
    +--------+------------+--------+
```

Reset the table for more test

```
UPDATE myTable SET toggle=0;
```

Comment: Failed to solve "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. "  If you want to try to edit have fun.

Comment: Thank you, your solution sounds reasonable enough for the current example and I will accept it. However I find it a bit confusing and I think I will take another route (see my self response http://stackoverflow.com/a/43935489/999516 ).

Comment: Does it work for third example? I guess for N=5 it satisfy only first case of third example in question

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot do that in a single query, but you'd need a stored procedure that accepts the maximum number of rows to update as a parameter and then would go with something like

```
var rows_left = max_rows

while(rows_left > 0){
    select postal_code into cur_code, count(*) into cur_count
    from   yourTable
    group by postal_code
    having count(*) <= rows_left
    limit 1

    update yourTable
    set    toggle = 1
    where postal_code = cur_code

    rows_left  = rows_left - cur_count
}
```

This is just some pseudo code to give you the general idea, you'll have to translate this into proper MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that the real dataset is more complex and I need to guarantee randomness in the selection of the groups that will be updated, I will probably end up doing something like this; so for the sake of sharing:

```
set @N:=2;
set @i:=0;
select postalcode,sum(NBR)
from (
    SELECT postalcode
            , if(@i+NBR>@N,0,1) as elected 
            , if(@i+NBR>@N,@i,@i:=@i+NBR) as indice
            , NBR
    FROM (  SELECT postalcode,COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS NBR FROM myTable GROUP BY postalcode ORDER BY RAND() ) A
    GROUP BY postalcode
    having elected= 1
    ORDER BY postalcode
) a GROUP BY postalcode
;
```